# how to edit records in the database using Tryton code

Tags: python, database, python-2.7, tryton

I want to edit (add or delete) records in the database using Tryton code.

Which function or method should I use to modify records in Tryton?

Example:

```
status=fields.Char("status")
```

How can I delete all records of field `status` and add a new one which has the value `status1`?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the ORM methods in order to search for the values you want and then delete them. So for example:

```
pool = Pool()
Model = pool.get('your.model.name')

records = Model.search([('status', '=', 'search_value')])
Model.delete(records)
```

In order to create new ones just use a the create method with a list of dictionaries. Each dictionary key must be the name of the field, and their value the value you want yo set. So for example:

```
values = [{'state': 'one'}, {'state': 'two'}]
Model.create(values)
```

Will create two records, one with state == 'one' and the other with state == 'two'